# HDD not recognized in Windows

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I just went from Ubuntu to Win7. Installed to my SSD etc.. all fine. But my secondary HDD isn't showing up in "Computer" but do so in Disk Management, but without a drive letter.

So how can I go about fixing this? I have no need to keep the content of the drive, so if it needs formatting or similar it's no problem. But I tried booting a live win7 CD and format the drive from there, but it wasn't available as an option since the drive most likely has some Linux format.

Do I delete the partitions? There's two of them, one with 100mb and one with 456gb. And if so, how and with what?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the disc is formatted with a Linux file system (probably ext4) and Windows cannot natively work with it.

In Disk Management create a partition on this disc. After that you will be able to format it.

Comment: I can't find any option to create a partition from Disk Management.

Comment: Right click on the disc. Try these instructions https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309170.aspx

Comment: There's no option to create a new volume when right clicking. It's all grayed out except "Delete Volume"

Comment: There's no option or the option is grayed out? Anyway, I would delete volume.

Comment: There's no option at all. But all other remaining options are grayed. Should I delete both the 100mb and the 465gb volume?

Answer (score 0):

As you've moved from Linux Distro i.e. Ubuntu, the drive has ext2/3/4 format. And Microsoft Windows doesn't support ext format's. So you need to delete ext partition and make new NTFS partition. This can be done either by using Gparted disk or booting with Ubuntu live CD and using disks application to erase existing partition and creating new partition. If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 or above Gparted application can also be found in live CD.